# Retrieve child node value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

here is the XML i am using
there are multiple instances of LineItemDetails i posted only one of it ...

```
<LineItemDetail>
    <DetailNumber>1</DetailNumber> 
    <LineItemNumber>1</LineItemNumber> 
    <BatchSequenceNumber>1</BatchSequenceNumber> 
    <RecordSequenceWithinBatch>1</RecordSequenceWithinBatch> 
    <ChargeAmount Name="GrossBilled">365.380</ChargeAmount> 
    <Tax>
        <TaxType>Tax</TaxType> 
        <TaxAmount Name="Billed">15.630</TaxAmount> 
        <TaxBreakdown>
            <TaxCode>MN</TaxCode> 
            <TaxAmount Name="Billed">15.630</TaxAmount> 
        </TaxBreakdown>
    </Tax>
    <AddOnCharges>
        <AddOnChargeName>ISCAllowed</AddOnChargeName> 
        <AddOnChargePercentage>-9</AddOnChargePercentage> 
        <AddOnChargeAmount>-32.880</AddOnChargeAmount> 
    </AddOnCharges>
    <TotalNetAmount>348.130</TotalNetAmount> 
    <CouponDetails>
        <TicketOrFIMIssuingAirline>160</TicketOrFIMIssuingAirline> 
        <TicketOrFIMCouponNumber>1</TicketOrFIMCouponNumber> 
        <TicketDocOrFIMNumber>2649488544</TicketDocOrFIMNumber> 
        <CheckDigit>6</CheckDigit> 
        <CurrAdjustmentIndicator>USD</CurrAdjustmentIndicator> 
        <ElectronicTicketIndicator>E</ElectronicTicketIndicator> 
        <AirlineFlightDesignator>MR</AirlineFlightDesignator> 
        <FlightNo>885</FlightNo> 
        <FlightDate>2013-04-03</FlightDate> 
        <FromAirportCode>ULN</FromAirportCode> 
        <ToAirportCode>HKG</ToAirportCode> 
        <SettlementAuthorizationCode>861FBKOPVEZZ4</SettlementAuthorizationCode> 
        <Attachment>
            <AttachmentIndicatorOriginal>N</AttachmentIndicatorOriginal> 
        </Attachment>
    </CouponDetails>
</LineItemDetail>
```

The above is the XML doc.
 i need to retrieve the value of the tag `<TaxCode>`.

Till now i got this far

```
var tax = from d in doc.Root.Descendants("Tax") select d;

foreach (var p in tax)
{
    taxcode= p.Element("TaxCOde").Value;
}
```

Comment: typo maybe: "TaxCOde"?

Comment: Do you have any namespaces in the XML?  The answers below should work - if you're still getting null values then I bet it's a namespace issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  XDocument DocumentObject = XDocument.Load(yourxml); 
  IEnumerable<XElement> Tax= from TaxInfo in DocumentObject.Descendants("Tax") select  TaxInfo;

            foreach (var t in Tax)
            {
                TaxType = (string)t.Element("TaxType");

            }
```

Comment: Not sure how this is the answer, since it returns `TaxType` and the code OP posted is looking for `TaxCode`....?

Comment: thnx kanith ..... just that it should have been .....<XElement> Tax= from TaxInfo in DocumentObject.Descendants("TaxBreakdown") select  TaxInfo;

Answer (score 1):

`p.Element("TaxCOde")` checks only direct children of `p` (`<Tax>` element), so it finds nothing.

Try that:

```
foreach (var p in tax)
{
    taxcode= (string)p.Element("TaxBreakdown").Element("TaxCode");
}
```

I used `(string)XElement` conversion instead of `XElement.Value` property, because it will not throw `NullReferenceException` when element is not found.

***Edit***

Test code for your sample XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("source.txt");

var lineItemDetails = doc.Descendants("LineItemDetail");

foreach (var lineItemDetail in lineItemDetails)
{
    var tax = lineItemDetail.Element("Tax");
    var taxCode = (string)tax.Element("TaxBreakdown").Element("TaxCode");
}
```

`taxCode` is `MN`.

Comment: still not working , now i am getting this error -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When i tried this

Comment: @user2660107 Is that XML you've posted you're whole document, or just a part of real one?

Comment: Does every `<tax>` element has structure like the one you've posted?

Comment: See updates in original codes i posted an instance of the LineItemDetail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach (var p in tax)
 {
   taxcode= p.Element("TaxBreakdown").Element("TaxCode").Value;
 }
```

Comment: still NO result Ajay ....

i did this

 var tax = from t in doc.Root.Descendants("Tax") select t;
            foreach (var t in tax)
            {  
                    taxcode = p.Element("TaxBreakdown").Element("TaxCode").Value;  
            }

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to use an XmlDocument? one you've loaded the xml in the document you could do this (I've declared the XmlDocument as `doc`):

```
foreach(XmlElement elem in doc.GetElementsByTagName("TaxCOde"))
     taxcode = elem.InnerText;
```

I've written this using only my memory, so I'm sorry if I've made some grammar or syntax mistakes

Comment: i am getting this Error
  'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementsByTagName' and no extension method 'GetElementsByTagName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's not an XDocument, It's an XmlDocument, you have to add the "using. System.Xml" at the top of your code. ;)

Comment: Really? wow... I have my code here working.... It's strange to see the namespace Linq in the reference that I told you. Have you donne all this steps? 1- XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument() 2-doc.Load(pathtoYourDocument) 3- doc.GetElementsByTagName(Name) ? This should work!!